# Additional field in FrontendUser not saved

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

The System i am using is set-up as following:

Typo3 8.7.27, MariaDB 10.3.16, PHP 7.0.33

I've extended the `FrontendUser` with additional some additional fields. However if i call the `action create` the user will be created/saved, but the fields: `confirmation_token` & `reg_source` will not be saved. The thing is, if i clear the cache it works for some time, but after several minutes/hours the problem re-appears.

The 'create' action looks as following:

```
/**
* action create
*
* @param \CODEMASCHINE\CmCoursefinder\Domain\Model\FrontendUser $user
* @return void
*/

public function createAction(\CODEMASCHINE\CmCoursefinder\Domain\Model\FrontendUser $user) {
 $feGroup = $this->userGroupRepository->findByUid(1);
 $random_token = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,8); //the token is generated properly

 $user->setPid($this->settings['usersStoragePid']);
 $user->addUsergroup($feGroup);
 $user->setEmail($user->getUsername());

 if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE'){
   $this->userRepository->add($user);
   $user->setRegSource(3);
   $this->redirect('list');
 } else {
   $user->setRegSource(2);
   $user->setDisable(1);
   $user->setTxCmcoursefinderConfirmationToken($random_token); //the token is there. it is not empty

   $this->userRepository->add($user);
   $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

   $pageUid = 418;
   $uri = $this->uriBuilder->reset()
     ->setCreateAbsoluteUri(true)
     ->uriFor('confirm', array('user' => $user->getUid(), 'confirmationToken' => $user->getTxCmcoursefinderConfirmationToken()),'User');
   $mailSubject = "a Email-Subject";
   $mailBody = "To Confirm your account please go to $uri "
   $this->redirect('complete');
 }
}
```

The fields `confirmation_token` & `reg_source` in 'ext_tables.php':

```
$newColumns = Array (
    'tx_cmcoursefinder_confirmation_token'  => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cm_coursefinder/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_cmcoursefinder_domain_model_frontenduser.confirmationToken',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim'

            ),
    ),

    'reg_source'  => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cm_coursefinder/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_cmcoursefinder_domain_model_frontenduser.regSource',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 1,
            'eval' => 'trim'

        ),
    )
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('fe_users', $newColumns, 1);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'tx_cmcoursefinder_confirmation_token', '', 'after:email');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'reg_source', '', 'after:email');
```

Configuration/Typoscript/setup.txt

```
config.tx_extbase{
  persistence{
    classes{
      CODEMASCHINE\CmCoursefinder\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
        mapping {
          tableName = fe_users
          recordType = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? if you need more info, please feel free to comment.

Comment: I see you make a difference between being logged in the backend and not? Does that make a difference when this action runs?

Comment: Could be. The idea behind that is to check if the user was created manually in backend or the form. This is important for statistics. The intention was to implement the 'reg_source' field.

Comment: Sounds like your form action is cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to make your class a global replacement of the given class.

the [typoscript reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/Index.html) suggests something like:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    CODEMASCHINE\CmCoursefinder\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
        mapping {
            tableName = fe_users
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't added this snippet in my question, but i already have it in the code. i will add it ASAP to the question. Thanks for bringin that up.